# Parse Regex in Cookie Response

Tags: java, regex, cookies

I have a cookie string that looks like this

```
...1_92_37.7795%2C-122.41953_87_DT...
```

I want to get the lat/long (in this case 37.7795, -122.41953) form this string. So far my regex and google ninja skills have been insufficient. Does anyone know the right regex to do this? I'm pretty sure the lat/long will always be at minimum 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast way to decide your problem. I hope it'll help you:

```
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1_92_37.7795%2C-122.41953_87_DT");

while (matcher.find()) // jcc, sorry
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group()));

System.out.println(numbers);
```

Output:

```
[37.7795, -122.41953]
```

Next time, please, write *your attempts* to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was in between a few things and next time I will post my attempts, but I knew what I'd gotten was too verbose to be close to what you provided.